# List installed meta packages in APT

Tags: apt

Meta packages are packages that do not install anything by themselfs, but are dependent on other packages. How do I list the installed meta packages on my system?

Comment: I think there's no other way than the brute force one: check all installed packages and report those whose installed files are only `/usr/share/doc/$pkg/(copyright|changelog)*`.

Answer (score 7):

I used:

```
apt-cache search . | grep -i "metapackage\|meta-package"
```

combined with:

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

in the following script:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
    FS=" - ";
    findmeta="apt-cache search . | grep -i \"metapackage\|meta-package\"";
    while ((findmeta | getline) > 0) meta[$1]=$2;
    FS=" ";
    findinstalled="dpkg --get-selections";
    while ((findinstalled | getline) > 0) {
        if ($1 in meta) print $1" - "meta[$1]
    }
}'
```

On one line:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=" - ";findmeta="apt-cache search . | grep -i \"metapackage\|meta-package\""; while ((findmeta | getline) > 0) meta[$1]=$2; FS=" "; findinstalled="dpkg --get-selections"; while ((findinstalled | getline) > 0) {if ($1 in meta) print $1" - "meta[$1]}}'
```

Example results:

```
emacs - GNU Emacs editor (metapackage)
exim4 - metapackage to ease Exim MTA (v4) installation
linux-headers-amd64 - Header files for Linux amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-image-amd64 - Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
xfce4 - Meta-package for the Xfce Lightweight Desktop Environment
xserver-xorg-input-all - X.Org X server -- input driver metapackage
```

Comment: I can confirm that the first command above works and it really finds metapackages. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following command, that list the name of every installed package that has
the string `"metapackage"` in its section field in `apt-cache show` output:

```
apt-cache show $(dpkg-query -Wf '${Package}\n') | 
  awk '$1 == "Package:" { pkg = $2 }; 
       $1 == "Section:" && $2 ~ /metapackage/ { print pkg }'
```

Comment: Maybe you mean “Description” field? But then, there is also (at least) “meta-package” and “meta package”...

Comment: @angus: no, I mean exactly *section* field: at least in Debian and in Ubuntu **real** metapackages are in section `metapackages` and `multiverse/metapackages`.

Comment: Isn't (for example) `emacs` a metapackage? I have it in section “editors”. Its description says: “The GNU Emacs editor (metapackage)”. (?) What's an example of a package in section “metapackage”? I couldn't find any :-/.

Comment: OK, with `perl -n00e 'print if /^Section: .*metapackage/m' /var/lib/apt/lists/*Packages` I found 4 of them. I don't think it's a very reliable method...